# Почему вызов функции в другом потоке фризит основной?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть класс для работы с базами данных, он унаследован от QObject
Для него есть свой поток.

```
bool dataBaseController::connectDB(QString s, QString d, QString l, QString p) //taking server dbName log and pass
{                                                                              // and trying to connect to new DB
    if(s.isEmpty() || d.isEmpty())
        return false;



    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setDatabaseName("Driver={SQL SERVER};Server=" + s+";Database=" + d + ";Trusted_Connection=no;");
    db.setUserName(l);
    db.setPassword(p);
    connectionTimer.singleShot(5*1000,[this](){

        if(!dbChanged){
        emit this->connectionTryTimeout();
        }
    });
    if(db.open()){
        dbOpen = true;
        dbChanged = true;
        emit this->connected();
        connectionTimer.stop();

        server = s;
        db_name = d;
        login = l;
        password = p;

        return true;

    }
    else{
        emit this->connectionTryTimeout();
        connectionTimer.stop();
        lastDbError = db.lastError().text();
        dbChanged = false;
    }

}
```

Внутри приложения у меня есть окно настроек, где я могу указать новые параметры подключения.

```
void progSettings::on_dbSave_clicked()
{
    QString server = ui->dbHost->text();
    QString dbName = ui->dbName->text();
    QString login = ui->dbLogin->text();
    QString password = ui->dbPassword->text();
    ui->dbSave->setEnabled(false);
    setCursor(Qt::BusyCursor);
    connect(dbController,dbController->connected,[this,server,dbName,login,password](){
        QSettings settings( "settings.conf", QSettings::IniFormat );
        dbChanged = true;
        QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Подключение к БД"), tr("База данных подлкючена успешно!"));

        settings.setValue("srvcfg/db_host",server);
        settings.setValue("srvcfg/db_name",dbName);
        settings.setValue("srvcfg/login",login);
        settings.setValue("srvcfg/password",password);
        settings.sync();
        disconnect(dbController,dbController->connected,0,0);
        ui->dbSave->setEnabled(true);
        setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    });
    connect(dbController,dbController->connectionTryTimeout,[this](){
        disconnect(dbController,dbController->connectionTryTimeout,0,0);
        QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Подключение к БД"), tr("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных!\n") +
                                 dbController->lastDbError);

        ui->dbSave->setEnabled(true);
        setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    });
    dbController->connectDB(server,dbName,login,password);
    qDebug() << "freeze";
}
```

Если я ввожу некорректные данные подключения(ip например), то интерфейс зависает(`qDebug() << freeze` выводится только после `QMessageBox` и срабатывания слотов) . И даже  `connectionTimer.singleShot` не срабатывает вовремя.

Что я делаю не так, раз функция в другом потоке фризит мой интерфейс?

Comment: то, что функция принадлежит классу, объект которого запущен в другом потоке, ещё не значит, что при ее вызове она автоматически запустится в другом потоке. Вам нужно написать код так, что бы функция запускалась там, где нужно. Но если соединить правильно, то может и получится.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. 
Действительно, если запускать функцию через connect, то все работает корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, надо было связывать все через connect:

```
 connect(this,SIGNAL(tryConnectDb(QString, QString, QString, QString)),
            dbController,SLOT(connectDB(QString, QString, QString, QString)));

 connect(dbController,SIGNAL(connected(bool)),this, SLOT(dbConResult(bool)));
```

```
void progSettings::on_dbSave_clicked()
{


    QString server = ui->dbHost->text();
    QString dbName = ui->dbName->text();
    QString login = ui->dbLogin->text();
    QString password = ui->dbPassword->text();
    ui->dbSave->setEnabled(false);
    setCursor(Qt::BusyCursor);

    emit tryConnectDb(server,dbName,login,password);

}
```

```
void progSettings::dbConResult(bool result)
{

    if(result){
        dbChanged = true;

        QSettings settings( "settings.conf", QSettings::IniFormat );        

        settings.setValue("srvcfg/db_host",ui->dbHost->text());
        settings.setValue("srvcfg/db_name",ui->dbName->text());
        settings.setValue("srvcfg/login",ui->dbLogin->text());
        settings.setValue("srvcfg/password",ui->dbPassword->text());

        settings.sync();

        QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Подключение к БД"), tr("База данных подлкючена успешно!"));
    }
    else{
        QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Ошибка!"), tr("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных!\n") +
                                 dbController->lastDbError);
    }
    ui->dbSave->setEnabled(true);

    setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
}
```